# How to filter by request user in Django-filter model

Tags: django, django-filters

Im using django-filter package and i want to know how can i pass queryset in ModelChoiceFilter of  request user in my django-filter model

I updated with view list and this **init** functions doesnt have an affect for some reason

filters.py

```
class PresenceDateFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    work_date = DateTimeFromToRangeFilter(
        widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(
            attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'},
        ))

    class Meta:
        model = PresenceDetailInfo
        fields = ('presence_info__counter_presence',
                  'work_date',
                  )
```

models.py

```
class PresenceDetailInfo(models.Model):
    presence_info = models.ForeignKey(PresenceListInfo, default=None, null=True,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='details_info')

class PresenceListInfo(models.Model):
    counter_presence = models.ForeignKey(CounterParty, default=None, null=True,
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CounterParty(models.Model):
    counter_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='counter_user')
```

views.py

```
class ShowPresenceInfoList(AccessMixin, ListView):
    model = PresenceDetailInfo
    template_name = 'common/presence_info.html'
    context_object_name = 'details_list'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowPresenceInfoList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        list_of_dates = PresenceDateFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context['form'] = list_of_dates.form
        context['dates'] = list_of_dates.qs

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
        current_counters = CounterParty.objects.filter(counter_user=current_user)

        if current_user.is_superuser:
            qs = PresenceDetailInfo.objects.all().select_related('presence_info', ).order_by(
                'work_date')
        else:
            qs = PresenceDetailInfo.objects.filter(presence_info__counter_presence__in=current_counters).select_related(
                'presence_info', ).order_by('work_date')
        word = PresenceDateFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs, request=self.request)
        return word.qs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it in the init inside the class PresenceDateFilter

```
def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, *, request=None, user=None, prefix=None):
        super().__init__(data=data, queryset=queryset, prefix=prefix)
        self.filters['presence_info__counter_presence'].queryset = CounterParty.objects.filter(counter_user=user)
```

You can customize the query, in the example it will return all the objects in the model and also get the user from request.user.

Comment: I got None when im trying to get user by your method

Comment: I will add models in my question mb its gotta be better

Comment: try with: 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
self.filters['presence_info__counter_presence'].queryset = CounterParty.objects.filter(counter_user=self.request.user)

Comment: Now i got an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: Your first method didnt have an errors but queryset was not affected at all 

I mean it was hiding some values but not all and it was hiding wrong values

Comment: Kirill_N, have you solved the problem? I'm having the same problem see my question here, and still do not know the solution. I've made some debug with help of print() function and found that my RangeFilter is initialized twice, first time in the very beginning, when I start my server (runserver), with default parameters, without context, with empty queryset. Second time it is initialized when called by PropertyFilter, with context, but for some reason the filter form on the web page is generated on the base of the first instance, so my form "doesn't know" the price diapason.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your view:

```
    class PresenceListView(ListView):
        model = PresenceDetailInfo
        template_name = 'presence_list.html'
        context_object_name = 'presence_list'
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            queryset = super().get_queryset()
            filter = PresenceDateFilter(
                self.request.GET,
                queryset=queryset,
                request=self.request,  # pass the request object to the filter
            )
            return filter.qs
```

And then pass the queryset in the init inside the class PresenceDateFilter

```
    def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, *, request=None, prefix=None):
            super().__init__(data=data, queryset=queryset, prefix=prefix)
            if request is not None and request.user.is_authenticated:
                self.filters['presence_info__counter_presence'].queryset = (
                    CounterParty.objects.filter(counter_user=request.user)
                )
```

Comment: Its not working  for some reason i updated my question with my ListView

Comment: I would like to see your models

Comment: i added my models already in my question